# Como poner método onBackPressed() en un PreferenceFragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment

Tengo un problema con un PreferenceFragment, he intentando poner un Toolbar o un Actionbar con un boton de regreso, pero los metodos que he usado no funcionan, lo que necesito es que al dar clic al boton "Atras" me devuelva a otra actividad, porque si presiono el boton de "Atras" me regresa al MainaActivty y no quiero que me regrese a esa clase, el metodo

> onBackPressed()

Parece que no funciona, hay alguna forma de hacer esta funcion?

Esta es mi clase:

```
> package com.example.enriq.myapplication;
> 
> import android.content.SharedPreferences; import
> android.graphics.Color; import android.os.Bundle; import
> android.preference.PreferenceFragment; import
> android.preference.PreferenceManager; /**  * Created by Enriq on
> 08/03/2018.  */
> 
> public class ConfiguracionesFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
> 
>     private String PREFS_KEY = "mispreferencias";
> 
>     @Override
>     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
>         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>         addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.configuraciones);
> 
>     }
> 
> 
>     @Override
>     public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
> 
>         super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
>         getView().setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
>         getView().setClickable(true);
> 
>         SharedPreferences preferencia = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
>         SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferencia.edit();
>         String valor = preferencia.getString("opcion1", "");
>         editor.putString("opcion1", "");
>         ((Principal) getActivity()).actualizar();
>         editor.apply();
> 
>     }
> 
> }
```

Comment: hola kike usando PreferenceFragment puedes usar onDetach()  ya que no existe un listener, agregué respuesta, saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando un [PreferenceFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html) no es posible sobreescribir `onBackPressed()` en este caso usa `onDetach()` :

```
@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();

    //Do your process here!

}
```

Comment: Si funciona pero el problema es que ahora al dar clic para volver muestra por un momento el mainactivity y luego la clase que le indique.